# Docker --add-host and Docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have 2 containers: PL and SL, both of them are on the same host (my pc - windows).
Both of containers are created from Linux images.

These containers should be connected to each other:

Inside PL container there is a configuration file (this is in "volume"), and there I inserted the string: `sl_url`.

So this is how I created the PL container:

```
docker run -d -p 8084:8080 -p 8008:8009 -v C:\temp\conf:/opt/tomcat/conf --add-host="sl-url:<my_host_IP_address>" --platform=linux <pl_image_name>
```

As you can see, `sl-url` is translated to my ip.
But it's not a good solution - because my ip may changes.

So I heard about docker compose (https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/),
how can I do it with docker compose?
I would like to create a container from image without insertion my IP every time. I would like to insert only the hostname.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why ask a so board question?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume "should be connected to each other" means, that you can reach an application in container `PL`, which binds to a port, from container `SL`, or vice versa.

You can achieve that with docker compose. Here's a minimal `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  SL:
  image: SL                 # or whatever the full image name is
  container_name: sl
  networks:
    - my_network

  PL:
  image: PL                 # or whatever the full image name is
  container_name: sl
  networks:
    - my_network

networks:
  my_network:
    name: my_network
    driver: bridge
```

You should then be able to reach container `SL` from container `PL` using simply `sl.my_network`. Try for example:

```
docker exec -it pl bash                         # with this command you enter container pl
ping sl.my_network
```

This assumes your container has `bash` and `ping` installed. You can use this URI (`sl.my_network`) in any config inside your containers. Docker DNS will resolve it for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! do you mean that I should insert my hostname in "my_network" field? and what about the string "sl-url" which is displayed in the properties file of PL and it represents the SL server? I need to put it somehow in the docker compose file? thanks, Ron

Comment: Hi, my answers shows you how to reach one container (sl) from the other container (pl), because you said "These containers should be connected to each other:". If that is what you want to do, you don't need to change anything, but I suspect, the idea of `--add-host="sl-url:<my_host_IP_address>"` is to reach your container over a network from an entirely different computer, e.g. the internet. Could you maybe clarify, what exactly you want to do?

Comment: 10x, I will clarify.I have a PL container which with Tomcat (+ war file). inside this container, I have a properties file - sl.properties. inside this file,I have some configurations about the PL service. This file also contains: services.url=http://sl-url:8085/core_sl_env4 - this property connects between two containers: PL and SL. this service.url is actually the SL url. That's why I added to host: --add-host="sl-url:<my_host_IP_address>". I inserted to the sl.properties file the string "sl-url", but I could inserted there my_host_IP_address,this is the same thing,this is why I use host file

Comment: BTW, PL and SL are on the same docker host (my machine). What do you suggest? thanks again! :)

Comment: If you use the docker-compose.yml I posted, both container will be on the same docker network `my_network` (feel free to change the name, but do it consistently, i.e. at all places) then your config would simply read `services.url=sl.my_network:8085/core_sl_env4` there is no need for the config to know your host IP

Comment: Also try the `docker exec ...` part form my answer, I guess it would give you a better feeling for how this works, if your container has telnet, try `telnet sl.my_network 8085` to connect to your sl application

Comment: If this answered your question, it is customary to accept the answer :)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and let you know :) amm..I'm not sure I fully understand why you use the networks section in the docker-compose.yml, I mean - why I can't write simply: services.url=sl:8085/core_sl_env4 instead of: services.url=sl.my_network:8085/core_sl_env4 ? thanks again!